# Dialogflow V2 Context and Action using API JSON

Tags: node.js, json, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to develop a bot with Google DialogFlow, but I have a problem trying to access to a specific `Action` within an `Intent`.

I need to receive the variables (name, color) that are configured in the `Action` of the `Intent`:

[image]

But, when I do a query to DialogFlow:

```
{
    "queryInput": {
        "text": {
            "text": "I need something",
            "languageCode": "en-US"
        }
    },
    "queryParameters" : {
        "contexts" : [ "I put all contexts created here" ]
    }

}
```

The bot skip the created `action` and continues to the `Default-Intent`

Unfortunately, there is not enough information in Dialogflow docs about this, do you know if I have to send the name of that specific action via the JSON too? What could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. To access the `context` and use `action parameters`, the estructure is

```
 "queryParams" : {
 "contexts" : [{
       "name": "Name of the context",
       "lifespanCount": 2,
       "parameters": { "The parameters you are using in that Intent"}
 }]
 }
```

So, instead of `queryParameters` use `queryParams`.